# Set iframe url based on dynamic Url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, web

Does anybody know a javascript code that will detect the dynamic url of the page (?q=Chicken) and set the url of the iframe on the page to https://www.google.co.uk/?#q=Chicken. (I am not actually making a google search client!)

```
    Get - Text added to Url
    set
    Url of iframe to https://www.google.co.uk/?#q=Chicken
```

This will all be onload.

Comment: what server side language you are using ?

Comment: You can fetch the dynamic url, do a substring from `?` and get the params.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
<script>
function get_url_parameter(name) {
  return decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&]' + name + '=' + '([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)').exec(location.search)||[,""])[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20'))||null
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', doc_loaded, false);
function doc_loaded() {
    //var url = 'https://www.google.co.uk/?#q=' + get_url_parameter('q');
    var url = 'http://example.com/?#q=' + get_url_parameter('q');
    document.getElementById('iframe_id').src = url;
}
</script>
<iframe src="#" id="iframe_id" width="1000" height="500"></iframe>
```

but it will not work for Google because it's sending an "X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN" response header :(

Comment: Worked perfectly for me. Thanks very much!

Comment: Is there any way to set the iframe to a different url if there is nothing added to the page's url? (If it is null set it to google homepage for example)

Comment: You could do something like this:
    if(get_url_parameter('q') == null) {
        var url = 'http://the-url-that-you-need/';
    } else {
        var url = 'http://example.com/?#q=' + get_url_parameter('q');
    }

Answer (score 1):

Try this , URL browsed "http://something.com/index.asp?search=anything

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

    $( document ).ready(function()
    {

    function getParameterByName(name) {
        name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
        var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
            results = regex.exec(location.search);
        return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }

     var urliframe =  "http://www.google.co.uk/?#q="+getParameterByName('search');

     $('#myIframe').attr('href',urliframe);

    });

    </script>

    <iframe id='myIframe' href='#'>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `location.search` in Javascript.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLUtils.search

So an example would be:

```
$('iframe')[0].src = "http://www.google.co.uk/" + location.search;
```

But, Google doesn't like to be in an iframe. You should try another site.